# What is the best way to protect battery of an always-powered iPad?

Tags: ipad, power-management, ipados

If an iPad is always powered, the best way to protect the battery is not to use it at all, i.e. the system charge the battery to 60% then only use the external power supply and only use the internal battery to provide transient high power to the system.

But there seems to be no way to let iPadOS do this. It will always charge the battery to 100% which is unhealthy and will increase the chance that the battery swell someday.

Then what is the best way?

Answer (score 2):

> *"which is unhealthy and will increase the chance that the battery swell someday."*

It's certainly true that keeping the battery more often within a 20% - 80% range will extend the life of a battery; but I think it's overstating it to say that 'keeping it at 100% is unhealthy and will cause swelling'.

iPadOS *does* have the same Optimized Battery Charging feature that macOS and iOS have -- the OS will charge to 80% if it's left fully charged for a long time. (Though it may depend on which model of iPad.)

> *the best way to protect the battery is not to use it at all, i.e. the system charge the battery to 60% then only use the external power
> supply and only use the internal battery to provide transient high
> power to the system.*

The battery is ALWAYS used, even while plugged in. The battery supplies the power to the board; the power supply charges the battery. You can't 'not use' the battery.

Comment: "iPadOS does have the same Optimized Battery Charging feature that macOS and iOS have -- the OS will charge to 80% if it's left fully charged for a long time" - that's amazing but I never hear about this feature, I only know it will first charge a phone to 80% and wait a while after which it will charge to 100%. Can you give some official reference for this feature? iPad Air 5 and iPadOS16+ is the target.

Comment: @iUnknown There doesn't seem to be any Apple documentation specific to iPadOS, though there are pages for the phone and Mac; but a quick google for 'ipad optimized battery charging" shows lots of people with iPads charging to 80%.

Comment: Hi, I'v used iPad Air 5 with iPadOS16.1 for 2 weeks, but the battery is always 100%. Is it just an old feature?